# Initializers in native arrays in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am just getting started with swift and I know we have a default array initialiser in swift and the syntax goes like this:

```
    let myArray = [Int](count:3 , repeatedValue:2)//int types [2,2,2]
```

But when I remove [Int] from the statement,it initialises the array with values (3,2).

```
    let myArray = (count:3 , repeatedValue:2)//[3,2]
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 9):

In the second example, you're getting a tuple, not an `Array`. If you don't want to specify `[Int]`, you still need to specify `Array`, like this:

```
let myArray = Array(count: 3, repeatedValue: 2)
```

Learn [more about tuples](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329) in the Swift book.